# Display SELECT COUNT result - Error: expects string, object given

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

In my project (Codeigniter - MVC. Database: Postgres) I need to display in the view a query result. But it returns the error:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
Filename: database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 622

My view:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d');
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1. ' +30 day'));  
$total_days = $this->sac->holidays($date1,$date2);
echo $total_days;
```

My model:

```
public function holidays($date1,$date2)
  {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table_holidays WHERE date_row between '".$date1."' AND  '".$date2."';");
    $return = $this->db->query($query);
    $result = $return->result();
     return json_encode($return->result()); 
   }
```

DB_driver.php

```
620 function is_write_type($sql)
621 {
622     if ( ! preg_match('/^\s*"?(SET|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|REPLACE|CREATE|DROP|TRUNCATE|LOAD DATA|COPY|ALTER|GRANT|REVOKE|LOCK|UNLOCK)\s+/i', $sql))
623     {
624         return FALSE;
625     }
626     return TRUE;
627 }
```

Does anyone could help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: You're returning the results of the query into `$query`, then trying to run a query against the results. That's not going to work.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: If you use CodeIgniter then why do you prepare the SQL statements incorrectly as a string? What is the purpose of having a framework if you do not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a query safe from SQL injection use query binding as shown here and explained [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings). This also optimises the query a bit by limiting the columns used for `COUNT` to one (instead of all columns i.e. *) and it also makes sure that it checks for empty result set and returns a count of zero in that case.

```
public function holidays($date1,$date2)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(startdate) as count FROM events WHERE startdate between ? AND ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, [$date1, $date2]);
    $row = $query->row();

    $count = ! empty($row) ? $row->count : 0; //$count=$row->count if $row is not empty, else $count=0 
    return json_encode($count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

Model:

```
public function holidays($date1,$date2)
  {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table_holidays WHERE date_row between '".$date1."' AND  '".$date2."';");
    echo $query->num_fields(); 
   }
```

View:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d');
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1. ' +30 day'));  
$this->sac->holidays($date1,$date2);
```

But as Dharman said, you are opened to SQL injection. You should use parameterized prepared statements.